# Sort by related field in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Notes and a NoteRefs fields where the NoteRefs has a foreign key to the Notes.  I need to query the Notes but order by the related field (ie. the NoteRefs' start_ref field).

How might I do that through the django ORM?  Here's kinda what works in SQL

```
SELECT 
   note.user_id,
   note.content,
   note.created,
   note.modified 
FROM noteref
INNER JOIN note
ON note.id = noteref.note_id
ORDER BY noteref.start_ref
```

I can't use `Note.order_by('related_field')`, because the related field isn't part of the Note Model.  From what I can tell, that seems to be what the documentation says to do.  How can I sort on the related field here?

**EDIT: Model information**

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class NoteRef(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, db_index=True)
    _order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    book = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    start_ref = models.IntegerField(max_length=8, db_index=True)
    end_ref = models.IntegerField(max_length=8, db_index=True)
    ref_range = models.IntegerField()
    passage = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: can you add more detail about your models

Comment: Why can't you select all NoteRefs ordered by start_ref and then call noteref.note.<field>?

Comment: Did you try `Note.objects.order_by("noterefs__start_ref")`, or whatever the related name for `noterefs` is?

Comment: Thomas, the relationship goes the other way around.  The NoteRef has the foreign key to the Note.

Comment: @yekta I understand that, but this should actually work. The [example in the documentation is quite poor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) — since `Event` has a relationship to `self`, but I'm pretty sure this does work.

Comment: @user1236327 That's kind of what I'm trying with this but its not ideal `NoteRef.objects.order_by('start_ref').select_related()[0].note`

Comment: On a side note, note that your SQL query will actually return duplicate Notes if they have multiple related NoteRefs.

Comment: Maybe this documentation is what you need? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Thomas, never knew about that!  Thank you so much - submit that as answer and I'll accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `Note.objects.order_by("noterefs__start_ref")`

The [documentation doesn't make this very clear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by), as it uses a `ForeignKey` to `self`, but it works.

Now, the docs also warn against the possibility of duplicate objects showing up if you have multiple `NoteRefs` for a single `Note`, so you should double-check this.

Comment: Thanks again!  I actually have another field which I can use to filter out duplicates.  Perfect.

Comment: I've been wanting this feature for literally years! How long has that worked?

Comment: @DavidEyk It's been documented since at least 1.0. There's always been the risk of duplicates, though

Comment: Figures! I've read that documentation many times and never noticed it.

Comment: Ah, the proper documentation for this is in the [Making Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) section of the docs.